# AS3: Can I create a new instance of an object but also using it as something to hold the return data?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I apologize if my title is not clear. I mean if I have a class that does something and returns a string, could I do something like this?

```
example:String = new MyClassThatReturnsStrings(1234);
```

If I cannot, how do I handle returns for a class? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an alternative to [taskinoor's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6489066/as3-can-i-create-a-new-instance-of-an-object-but-also-using-it-as-something-to-h/6489122#6489122), you could define the method as `static`:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public function formatNumber(number : Number) : String
    {
        return number.toString();
    }
}

var value : String = MyClass.formatNumber(1234);
```

Or you can skip the class entirely and declare the function globally:

```
package com.package.name
{
    public function formatNumber(number : Number) : String
    {
        return number.toString();
    }
}

var value : String = formatNumber(1234);
```

Answer (score 2):

A constructor can't return a value. You need to move the calculation that return something in another method other than constructor and after instantiating the class you need to call that method. Like this:

```
var myClass:MyClass = new MyClass();
var example:String = myClass.methodThatCalculateAndReturn(1234);
```

You can do this in one line if you don't need the object in anywhere else. Like this:

```
var example:String = (new MyClass()).methodThatCalculateAndReturn(1234);
```